# Animating SVG Path's stroke-dashoffset causes extreme drop in performance in Safari

Tags: css, svg

I have a simple `stroke-dashoffset` CSS animation on my site, it's what is causing those dashed lines to move in the gif below:

[image: My site's animation]

This run's fine on Chrome/Firefox on my Macbook. But when I open it on Safari there's an extreme drop in performance. Every now and then it will start running smooth for a second or so, and then go right back to being choppy and slow. It's somewhat unpredictable.

[I made a codepen](https://codepen.io/callgage/full/bygEXm) that uses the same SVG paths and animation - And the problem persists.

I noticed when I make the Safari window smaller, it smooths out very well. Which makes me think it has something to do with how many pixels it's drawing and how often it's drawing them.

I've been looking up this issue with every search phrase I can think of and can't find anything that would help me understand what's happening. I was wondering if anyone had any advice on a workaround for this? Or just some clarification on what is happening here. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `Timelines` tab of the Safari devtools — it seems animating the dash offset causes the whole layout to be invalidated and repainted: [here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/D8eOYv0r.png). This is similar to animating a margin vs animating a transform. Unless someone chimes in with a clever idea, it sounds like a browser optimization problem to me, something which you can't magically fix. You can always just disable the animation on certain browsers, although I do agree, it looks nice.

Comment: Report it as a [webkit bug](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/) maybe it will get fixed and no workaround will be necessary.

Comment: Dang. I'm surprised I couldn't find any posts anywhere about this topic. I feel like it would be a common issue.

Comment: Runs fine on my Safari 12.1/Mojave 10.14.4  mid-2015 Macbook Pro w/16GB

Comment: The same here:works fine on Safari 12.1

Comment: @MichaelMullany On Safari 11.1, it runs reasonably fast when just viewing the page, and lags heavily when inspecting the page. So it's entirely possible this is already fixed in newer versions of the browser.